# Live Streaming adobe media server video to HTML 5

Tags: flash, html5-video, rtmp, flash-media-server, adobe-media-server

I am looking for a way to broadcast my live video from my camera in flash to adobe media server and to display this video to HTML 5.

I have already gone through this [tutorial](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-develop/streaming-video-to-html5-apple-and-flash-enabled-devices/).This is related to video on demand but i have to stream live video taken from camera to HTML 5 .

Is it possible to stream live video to an HTML5 player?

Comment: Take a look here : [Adobe.com : Stream live media (HTTP)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WSd391de4d9c7bd609-52e437a812a3725dfa0-8000.html)

Comment: The tutorial link in the question is broken; it's going to a different site.

Comment: @akmozo I think your link may be need to be updated too.

Comment: @Panzercrisis The link was for Flash Media Server 4.5, it's visible via [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20141014181331/http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WSd391de4d9c7bd609-52e437a812a3725dfa0-8000.html), but Adobe has updated it to the last Adobe Media Server 5 [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/dev/stream-live-media-http.html), which is visible in the new link.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, using the HTML5 video tag.

Here's an example:

```
<video width="640" height="480" id="video" autoplay>
    <source src="http://myserver.com/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/mystream.m3u8" type="vnd.apple.mpegURL" />
    HTML5 video not supported.
</video>
```

The URL used here is important - this is the format of the stream URL:

http://[domain]/hls-live/livepkgr/[appinstance]/[event]/[streamname].m3u8

Comment: Where's a good link on how to set this up in the Adobe Media Server?